# maven-shade-plugin vs maven-assembly-plugin : undef Class-Path, support null Main-Class

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

I was quite happily using the `assembly` plugin, except that I’d have liked to change the `-jar-with-dependencies` part for a simpler `-with-dependencies`.
As I want both (the fat one and the regular one) jars published, I tried to switch to the `shade` plugin.

*(the solutions I have found to achieve that with the assembly plugin only work if I choose to publish only the fat jar)*

I have the feeling that the `shade` plugin lacks the `archive` section used by the `assembly` plugin, and that its support for manifest operations is not as good.

In that `<archive>` section, I could choose to void the Class-Path, by not using `<addClassPath>` (as for a fat jar, the class path seems irrelevant).
I could also choose to specify a Main-Class using a property which could be null, in that case the manifest entry would just not be added.

```
<archive>
    <manifest>
        <mainClass>${one-jar.mainClass}</mainClass>
    </manifest>
</archive>
```

With the `shade` plugin, I find none of these treats.

```
<transformers>
    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
        <manifestEntries>
            <Main-Class>${one-jar.mainClass}</Main-Class>
            <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
        </manifestEntries>
    </transformer>
</transformers>
```

**The problems :**

If I don’t try to hush the Class-Path (using the trick above was a quick shot at it), the original class-path is written to the manifest, which is plain useless for a self-contained jar.

If `${one-jar.mainClass}` is not defined (as in a non executable fat jar, in this case a MapReduce jar), the manifest entry is nicely omitted with the `assembly` plugin, but set to `(null)` in the `shade` plugin : the latter makes running the jar fail.

```
[hdfs@manager ~]$ hadoop jar ~/mapreduce-with-dependencies.jar path.to.my.MainClass …
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: null
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        …/…
```

*Why not remove that entry at all then ?*

This plugin section actually lays in my root pom.xml, which holds lots of plugin settings used by various unrelated projects, with the purpose of not having to rewrite whole plugin sections in those projects.

I can live with having to specify `<Class-Path>.</Class-Path>`, even though it’s a poor workaround trick, but I don’t want to rewrite `shade` configuration in my child projects just because of that problem.

I’d rather fall back to using the `assembly` plugin - unless I’m missing something !

Am I ?

Thanks for your thoughts and help :)

Comment: *I could also choose to specify a Main-Class using a property which could be null, in that case the manifest entry would just not be added.* But if you don't specify it, it won't be added, so why are you specifying it to begin with? Can you clarify what is the end goal here?

Comment: So if I understand correctly your issue is that your shade config here is not written to the children pom right? Especially the classpath

Comment: @Tunaki : as I said, that part is written in a shared global pom.xml. I do not want to copy/paste settings in children pom.xml, I want to use a property to specify the mainClass, and if it’s not there, it means I don’t want a mainClass. That’s how it worked using the assembly plugin.

Comment: Well that's unspecified behaviour, so even what the Assembly Plugin is doing may change... Why not have 2 executions, one with the main class, one without, and skip the right one?

Comment: I could to that. Duplicate the shade config in my root pom.xml and use two different profiles (one-jar-without-main and one-jar-with-main) . But what a mess just for the lack of if (value!=null) setClassPath(value); else /* do nothing */; …

Comment: The archive part is not under the responsibility of the assembly plugin is it ? I guess the assembly plugin delegates that to maven archiver, or does it ?

Comment: There seems to be a specification in the Maven Archiver not to put null stuff in manifest : https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifestEntries.html

Comment: Yeah the plugin relies on Maven Archiver, like the Shade plugin actually. The doc says that elements that isn't present won't be in the Manifest. But "isn't present" is a different than "present with an empty value" (plugin can't make the difference between null and empty)... You probably don't need to duplicate the config, although it's hard to tell with what you showed (where `one-jar.mainClass` is coming from?).

Comment: The link I posted in my comment shows an exact use case: if ${project.url} is missing, then it wont be in the manifest. one-jar.mainClass in my case is just a property in the child pom.xml, which can be missing too.